# How to show cutom post labels in options?

Tags: custom-post-types, dropdown

I have this code:

```
      $args=array(
        'public'   => true,
        '_builtin' => false
      );
      ?>
      <select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('posttype'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('posttype'); ?>">
          <?php foreach(get_post_types($args,'names') as $post_type) { ?>
              <option <?php selected( $instance['posttype'], $post_type ); ?> value="<?php echo $post_type; ?>"><?php echo $post_type; ?></option>
          <?php } ?>      
      </select>
```

I make custom posts

```
function my_post_type_interior_articles() {
        register_post_type( 'interior_articles',
                    array( 
                    'label' => __('Interior Design Articles'), 
                    'public' => true, 
                    'show_ui' => true,
                    'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
                    'menu_position' => 5,
                    'supports' => array(
                            'title',
                            'custom-fields',
                            'editor',
                            'excerpt',
                            'thumbnail')
                        ) 
                    );
    }

    add_action('init', 'my_post_type_interior_articles');
```

in dropdown shows **"interior_articles"**, but i need to show **"Interior Design Articles"**

How to show cutom post labels in options?

Comment: is this what you mean? (**last block of code**) http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18159/list-custom-post-types-in-dropdown/18172#18172

Comment: @Martin, I edit post, hope it help to understand what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to pull the Labels via `get_post_type_object();`

```
<?php 
$args=array(
  'public'   => true,
  '_builtin' => false
); 
$output = 'names';
$operator = 'and';
$post_types=get_post_types($args,$output,$operator); 
?>
<select id="" name="">

    <?php foreach ($post_types as $post_type ) {      
        $label_obj = get_post_type_object($post_type); 
        $labels = $label_obj->labels->name;
    ?>

        <option <?php selected( $instance['posttype'], $post_type ); ?> value="<?php echo $post_type; ?>"><?php echo $labels; ?></option>

    <?php } ?>

</select>
```

Read more here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type_object

Answer (score 0):

Theres a fix for that:

```
<?php 
          $args=array(
                     'public'   => true,
                     '_builtin' => false
                     ); 
                $output = 'names';
                $operator = 'and';
                $post_types=get_post_types($args,$output,$operator); 

          echo '<select name="customcategory">';
          echo '<option value="interior_articles">Interior Design Articles</option>';
          echo '<option value="another_post_type">Another Post Type</option>';
          echo '<option value="and_yet_another_post_type">And Yet Another Post Type</option>';
          echo '</select>';  
     ?>
```

probably not the ideal option but works for my setup

Comment: I think that too, but I make a plagin and need dinamyc dropdown